# Cannot read property fields of undefined

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-dom

I need to understand where I am going wrong in the below piece of code. The error screenshot is shown below.
[image]

```
HTML Template:-
<template>
   {name} 
</template>
 JS Controller:-
import { LightningElement,api,wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import LASTNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.LastName';

export default class FetchRecords extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields:LASTNAME_FIELD})
    contact;
        get name(){
            return this.contact.data.fields.LastName.value;
        }
}
```

Comment: Try `return this.contact.LastName;` assuming `recordId` is a Contact record Id I would expect `contact` to be a Contact SObject. Though you may also need a null guard as the data is loaded asynchronously `return this.contact ? this.contact.LastName : '';`.

Comment: @KeithC...using this.contact.LastName resolved the error but now in HTML template nothing is coming. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: That is because after the wired contact is populated, there's no reactive property which would make the component rerender. You can try to test this by forcing the rerender, just put {contact} within your template, and this should render it correctly, just to test.

Comment: @PrashantKashyap..in this case its displaying [object OBJECT] on the template....i tried using{contact.data}...same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue might be `get` might be getting called before wire gets executed as it is directly called without using `getFieldValue`.

The correct syntax as per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_wire_adapters_record) is to use `getFieldValue`

```
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';


@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields:LASTNAME_FIELD})
    contact;
        get name(){
            return getFieldValue(this.contact.data, LASTNAME_FIELD);
        }
```

Comment: Awesome man @Nagendra for helping me out..it was the real thorn in the flesh.